# Unit Testing issue in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

Whenever I try to run any of the test from my test suite in Visual Studio 2012 I get

> Test Failed - [test method name]
>
> Message: Failed to set up the execution context to run the test

and my test is not even started (i.e. the source of the test failure is pointing at the beginning of the test method:

> here--> TEST_METHOD([test method name])
> {
>
> }

What does this message mean, what could be the cause for it to appear and what should I do for my test to run correctly?

Comment: Could you submit this as a bug at http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio?

Comment: I had to use the --diag:out.txt parameter of vstest.console to point me in the right direction - it said "System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'client.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest." - the error wasn't quite right but it was enough for me to use dumpbin to see missing dependent .dll files.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After some more research I realized that I overlooked the fact that I changed the 'Output Directory' of the project containing the methods under test (which was a .dll) and was not in the same folder as my test project library, hence giving me the message:

> Message: Failed to set up the execution context to run the test

So the problem was solved by making sure that the .dll containing the methods under test was in the same folder as my test project library so that at run-time my test project could find the .dll.

Comment: This solution also applies to VS'15u3, (and likely VS'17, though I cannot confirm).

Comment: I'm running into this. So you're saying your can't make a common bin folder all projects build to outside their project folders? VS needs to fix this.

Comment: I changed my Output Directory but changing them back doesn't fix this. Can you give an example of the path that works for you?

Comment: Nvr mind. Just needed to set the UnitTest dll path to match the output of the project being tested.

Comment: Hum. I am under Visual Studio 2022, I have a C++ dll project ZEPROJECT and an C++ MS test project ZEPROJECTTEST. I am copying myself (with a post build event for ZEPROJECT) the ZEPROJECT DLL inside the folder where ZEPROJECTTEST.DLL is built (and I am verifying with my own eyes that the copy is executed) and I still have unresolved externals errors when building ZEPROJECTTEST.

Comment: To be precise : for each header ZEHEADER.h of ZEPROJECT (header which is naturally included in the source file of my test), for each exported free function declared in this header and for each member function of an exported class this header (member function whose declaration is in this header), if the definition is not in ZEHEADER.h but in ZEHEADER.cpp, then I have an unresolved external on this free or member function. I don't have these external errors anymore when I moreover include ZEHEADER.cpp in the source file of my test.

Comment: And this happens wheter or not I add ZEPROJECT as project reference to ZEPROJECTTEST.) This is strange.

Comment: And even more curiously, the error seem not to appear for non-absctract classes having no derived classes. (For them, including the header suffices. For the others, including header and source of base and derived is needed.)

Comment: To sum up, the errors are not only caused by the absence of the tested DLL next to the binaries of the testing project.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue and the previously mentioned suggestions did not fix it for me. My project uses some third party libraries and the paths to these are set up correctly in the compiler and linker settings of my VS project.

It turns out that the VS test engine was unable to find the libraries, so I added the paths to these libraries to the PATH environment variable. This fixed the issue for me.

Tip: Try running the unit tests from the command line using VSTest.Console.exe. The error messages helped me debug my issue more easily.

Comment: +1 for the tip of running VSTest.Console.exe. I added a .props file with a post-build copy to get all the DLL dependencies copied to the defined $(OutDir). Also, this question and answer are applicable to VS 2015 (that's what I'm using).

Comment: Just for the record - to use `VSTest.Console.exe`, one has to open the `Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio...`. In there it is possible to run unit tests by finding the appropriate DLL and then call `VSTest.Console.exe /Platform:x64 UnitTest.xyz.dll`. (x86 for 32bit)

Comment: Without being aware, I accidentally removed the `.dll` file of an external library that I had copied to the binary folder of my project.  I ran `VSTest.Console.exe` and it prompted me that I was missing that .dll file.

Answer (score 11):

For those searching for other answers, this turned out to be a problem finding all the DLLs needed.  I followed the advice above getting both the test dll and the dll to be test in the same location but still got this error.

My test DLL, out of its native environment, couldn't find its children DLL. You can figure out what is missing by running [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) . Adding the locations to these other DLL's to my path resolved the problem and everything now works.

Comment: For those who use Visual Studio, there are some dependent dlls located in `Configuration Properties`->`Linker`->`General`->`Additional Library Directories`

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error, and it was because I was using a debug DLL, and did not have debug c++ runtimes where they could be found.  I copied the debug c++ runtimes into the same directory and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error after including a third party dll (OpenCV) in my project. Adding the dll to path or dropping it in the system32 directory does work, but I have a better solution.

The test is run from a directory called AppX. In my case it is here:
.......OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio\Projects\TutorialOcr\x64\Debug\OcrTesting\AppX

I just dropped the dll in there and the test worked!

Answer (score 1):

The .dll created for the tests is run from the folder where it is built to. In my case "x64\UnitTests\Tests.dll". The rest of my application is in "x64\Debug\App.exe" and "x64\Release\App.exe".
My application depends on external dlls which are located in the root folder of the project, which is also the "Working Directory" specified for debug launch.

But the Test Explorer test launcher ignores that setting and always launches Tests.dll with working directory "x64\UnitTests", and then fails to find the dlls I depend on. Adding `SetCurrentDirectory("..\\..");` in, say, the test class constructor does not fix the problem, because the dll cannot even be loaded into memory if the static dependencies are not found.

I solved it by just setting the "Output Directory" to "$(SolutionDir)" for the UnitTests configuration. This causes the Tests.dll to be created in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error only in the Release configuration, because I accidentally used a debug lib as one of the library dependencies of my test project. ( same problem as bmann's post )

To find which library was causing the problem, I commented out all the test code and its includes, added one empty test, and removed my dependency libraies one by one until the test worked.