# Failed to Set up the execution context to run the test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

Here's my current setup:

- I've got a set of Unit Tests that run flawlessly
- I've got a set of libraries all compiled as static .lib
- The unit test project is compiled as a .dll and contains a number of classes

I recently added a class, namely MyCoolClass.h:

```
#include "AnotherBoringClass.h" // also inherits from BoringClass

class SuperCoolClass: public BoringClass
{
    /*
     * My super cool implementation
    */
protected:
    std::shared_ptr<AnotherBoringClass> myCoolPointer;
}
```

Everything is fine, compiles and so on. But when I try to add a unit test:

```
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include "MyCoolClass.h"

TEST_CLASS(MyTestClass)
    {
    public:
        /*
         * Bunch of super cool -working- tests
        */
        TEST_METHOD(MyBrokenTest)
        {
            auto myVar = std::make_shared<MyCoolClass>();  // as soon as I comment this line everything works!!!
        }
    }
```

When I comment the line as above everything work well! What am I doing wrong?

What I've tried:

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985590/vs-2013-unit-test-not-working-error-while-setting-up-execution-context), but I've got everything in the same output folder. Also, I make use of QuantLib and Boost, but all other Unit Tests work fine
- [Same as previous link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1c578f64-fc11-4207-8284-74075372337b/failed-to-set-up-the-execution-context-to-run-the-test?forum=vstest)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

After an endless effort to solve the problem, I finally did it. It was because I was using MKL linked statically, whereas my program was compiled using the option *Property -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library -> xxx DLL*.

Hope it helps!

Comment: FYI, I made a minor edit to your post so I could undo an accidental down vote made 10 days ago.  I probably swiped the button while working on my Surface Pro and commuting on a bumpy train ride home.