# Unit testing Inconsistent dll linkage leads to compilation error

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio-2013, native

New to c++ and trying to test a dll but keep getting

```
warning C4273: 'CRootFinder::SquareRoot' : inconsistent dll linkage
```

**RootFinder.h**

```
#ifdef MY_EXPORTS
#define API _declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define API _declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class API CRootFinder {
public:
    CRootFinder(void);
    double SquareRoot(double v);
};
```

**RootFinder.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "RootFinder.h"

double CRootFinder::SquareRoot(double v)
{
    return 0.0;
}
```

**Builds but gets warning above.**

Added reference to dll to unit test project

**unittest1.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include "../c source/RootFinder.h"
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace Tests
{       
    TEST_CLASS(UnitTest1)
    {
    public:

        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
        {
            CRootFinder rooter;
            Assert::AreEqual(
                // Expected value:
                0.0,
                // Actual value:
                rooter.SquareRoot(0.0),
                // Tolerance:
                0.01,
                // Message:
                L"Basic test failed",
                // Line number - used if there is no PDB file:
                LINE_INFO());
        }

    };
}
```

Won't build

> Error 2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall
>   CRootFinder::CRootFinder(void)" (__imp_??0CRootFinder@@QAE@XZ)
>   referenced in function "public: void __thiscall
>   Tests::UnitTest1::TestMethod1(void)"
>   (?TestMethod1@UnitTest1@Tests@@QAEXXZ)

Comment: No point in using two DLLs here, the C++/CLI compiler is perfectly capable of linking the managed test code .objs and the native code .objs being tested into a single DLL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile dll with MY_EXPORTS preprocessor marco. Add use it in test without MY_EXPORTS  definition macro.

In Visual Studio you can do that: `Project right click->Propertis->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions`, just add MY_EXPORTS to the list for dll project, and leave that list without MY_EXPORTS for test project.

And you need define constructor `CRootFinder()` in `RootFinder.cpp`.

Comment: This is  needed just for building the `dll` and definitely not the application that uses the `dll`.

Comment: @drescherjm, my mistake, seems I fixed it (=

Comment: @gomons - sorry, where do I do that?  I thought I am doing what you said.

Comment: If you use Visual Studio, than Project fight click->Propertis->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions, just add MY_EXPORTS to the list

Comment: It is for build dll. Do not place that macro to the Preprocessor Definitions when you build test.

Comment: @gomons - OK.  That solved warning, but build error is still there.  I did not define MY_EXPORTS in test.

Comment: Warning from linker. Seems like you not add .lib file to you test project.

Comment: Project right click->Propertis->Linker->Additional Library Directory, add to list path to folder where .lib file of your dll. Than Project right click->Propertis->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies, add to list .lib file

Comment: I removed dll reference from test project and added it again, but still have that error. ?

Comment: Hm... if you add dll to reference, it is the same as I describe above... I need time for thinking

Comment: Ha, you tries compile class in dll, but you can't do that

Comment: You can't export class, you should export every method of your class instead.

Comment: hmm :) take your time:)

Comment: I found. You forgot define constructor

Comment: Oh, yes. That's why.  buuut now error is Failed to set up the execution context to run the test.  maybe I will mark this as answer and make new question for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75442/discussion-between-gomons-and-o-o).

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195151/unit-testing-issue-in-visual-studio-2012