# "Failed to set up execution context" when running VC++ unit test with external dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-c++

I have a solution (available on Git at [this link](https://github.com/andry-tino/code-alive/tree/master/src/triangulator/src)) including one project (producing a DLL library) and a native unit test.

- Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 with VC++
- On Windows 10

The structure of my solution is the following:

```
./src
+--DelaunayTriangulator.UnitTest
|  |--DelaunayTriangulatorTest.cpp
|  |--DelaunayTriangulator.UnitTest.vcxproj
+--DelaunayTriangulator
|  |--DelaunayTriangulator.cpp
|  |--DelaunayTriangulator.h
|  |--DelaunayTriangulator.vcxproj
|--Triangulator.sln
```

#### The project

My source project works and builds fine. It links some libs (AFAIK, they are basically static libraries) which are just some [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/) stuff I need as dependencies. It also runs fine.

If you have a look at the [project](https://github.com/andry-tino/code-alive/blob/master/src/triangulator/src/DelaunayTriangulator/DelaunayTriangulator.vcxproj), you will find that I link those `.lib` files as part of Linker options:

```
<Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies>$(CGALDirPath)\build\lib\Debug\CGAL-vc140-mt-gd-4.12.lib;$(CGALDirPath)\auxiliary\gmp\lib\libgmp-10.lib;$(CGALDirPath)\auxiliary\gmp\lib\libmpfr-4.lib;..</AdditionalDependencies>
      ...
</Link>
```

#### The test project

The unit test project has been created by using the [native test project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh598953.aspx) walkthrough and template in Visual Studio. The [test project](https://github.com/andry-tino/code-alive/blob/master/src/triangulator/src/DelaunayTriangulator.UnitTest/DelaunayTriangulator.UnitTest.vcxproj) is also linking the same `.lib` files that the source project does. Following is the single test I have:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"

#include "../DelaunayTriangulator/DelaunayTriangulator.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;
using namespace CodeAlive::Triangulation;

namespace TriangulatorUnitTest {
    TEST_CLASS(DelaunayTriangulatorTest) {

    public:
        TEST_METHOD(PerformTriangulation) {
            DelaunayTriangulator* triangulator = new DelaunayTriangulator();
            int result = triangulator->Perform();

            Assert::AreEqual<int>(0, result, L"Wrong result", LINE_INFO());

            delete triangulator;
        }
    }; // class
} // ns
```

Before I linked those `.lib` files from CGAL, the project did build but did NOT run at all, showing this error message:

> Message: Failed to set up the execution context to run the test

#### The error

As soon as I added the `.lib` files, the project did build and the single unit test did run only if I left the `Assert` line uncommented (I had to comment all the code referencing my source project):

```
TEST_CLASS(DelaunayTriangulatorTest) {
public:
    TEST_METHOD(PerformTriangulation) {
        Assert::AreEqual<int>(0, 0, L"Wrong result", LINE_INFO());
    }
};
```

When I uncomment the code referencing my project (using the classes I define in my source project), then the same error message shows up when I try running the test:

```
TEST_CLASS(DelaunayTriangulatorTest) {
public:
    TEST_METHOD(PerformTriangulation) {
        DelaunayTriangulator* triangulator = new DelaunayTriangulator();
        int result = triangulator->Perform();

        Assert::AreEqual<int>(0, result, L"Wrong result", LINE_INFO());

        delete triangulator;
    }
};
```

I understand that this is due to some kind of issue with external references. What is wrong here?

Comment: Related (same error message, maybe different cause): [Unit Testing issue in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13195151)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So the issue here was kinda peculiar to my configuration but also generic enough to deserve an answer for other devs who might incur in this situation.

The problem was that the `.dll`s of my source project were not deployed to the test output folder. So you need to set `OutDir` in your test project properties:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
  <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
  <OutDir>$(ProjectDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</OutDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This will make the test actually copy the dlls not in the solution folder, but in the test project folder, and then the referenced source project dlls will be correctly copied. The test project file did not have an entry for `OutDir`, it seems that made MSBuild not copy the source artifacts.